# How to wait for reload in Playwright?

Tags: .net, playwright

We are using the Playwright dotnet and we have been using [`WaitForNavigationAsync`](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation) to wait for a page to reload.

However this is now deprecated and we are advised to use [`WaitForURLAsync`](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url) instead. As far as I can tell this will return immediately if I'm already on the URL that I'm waiting for which will be the case when expecting a reload. I have also looked at `WaitForLoadStateAsync` but that also appears to return immediately.

So given the new changes to the API what is the correct way to wait for a page to reload? We don't want to use `ReloadAsync` as the test is clicking buttons triggering navigation to the same URL.

Comment: Will something have changed in the newly reloaded page due to that button getting clicked? Wait for that instead. You shouldn't care whether the page reloads or not, only whether the state of the page has change due to your manipulations.

Comment: Yes I suppose so! But the data could be retrieved from a slow API request and I don't know how long the page takes to reload. So I'm just wondering if there is a potential risk that the reload is slow and the data takes a long time to load the it will exceed the timeout. I would feel more comfortable knowing that the page has been reloaded and can continue with my next assertion.

Comment: It is very annoying that the Playwright team have deprecated this method which a good number of us use safely and correctly.  I am in the same situation but as they [stated](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20853#issuecomment-1433572982) it is unlikely for the method to be removed (at least not before a v2 Playwright comes out), that I am sticking with it.

I might try to rally some people to try and get it undeprecated.  Failing that, I will just wait until it is fully removed as a method and then re-implement myself in a folked version.

Answer (score 0):

> How to wait for reload in Playwright?

Don't. Instead wait for an object to reach desired *changed* state after re-load and verify it using [web assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions).

```
await expect(page.getByText('Welcome')).toBeVisible({timeout:5000});
```

Comment: Yes I get that but that desired state has to be reached within a certain timeout. Say I have a website that is served slowly (size, slow server etc.) and I wan't to make sure that once the content is served by the server, some specific thing happens within 5 seconds (maybe an AJAX call or something along those lines) - if I don't know when the browser has reloaded then I don't know when to wait - if the initial load is low I can easily hit the timeout. That's why I would like to know when the browser has reloaded and I'm ready to wait for the desired changed state.

Comment: Again , you don't need to know that. You can verify in sum total (reload+ element displayed ) that by an reasonable time page reaches to a certain expected  state like for example "Welcome"displayed otherwise timeout failure.